# Temporal value of a present tense verb in a predicate nominative statement?

Tags: verbs

Does the present tense equative verb ("is") in a predicate nominative construction necessarily have temporal value, or does it depends on the statement itself?

For example, "Lebron James ***is*** the best player in the NBA," might be applicable now, but the time will come, once he retires, when the statement no longer applies. At that point we would say, "Lebron James ***was*** the best player in the NBA." So, does this mean that the present tense verb "is" in the first statement is both equative ***and*** has temporal value?

On the other hand, the statement "Denali ***is*** the highest mountain in North America" will (presumably) be as true in one hundred years as it is today. So, does this mean that the verb "is" in this statment has no temporal value, but simply **equates** the subject with the complement?

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: However logical, it can't be relevant what we speculate might be true in future, any more than it matters grammatically whether the world is flat, or Noah Shipwright knew what he was doing.

Consider the mountain statement from a theoretical future time. How would you describe Denali, please? 'Denali is…' hardly. 'Denali was…' hardly. 'Denali, then…' hardly. Either 'Denali, then and now…' or just 'Denali, the highest mountain…'

If any of those could in any way affect the meaning of the original statement, then it might be needful to worry about its grammar.

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't answer the question, which is: does the equative verb have temporal value, or is does it simply equate the subject with its complement?

Comment: Uh… OK; there is no temporal value